# Discord.NET - Get Which Type of Exception was Thrown in Command

Tags: c#, exception, bots, discord, discord.net

I thought it would be easier to throw exceptions if say a person didn't have the right permissions to run a command, or there is a cooldown, or whatever, instead of just handling that *every... single... time*. So I made my own exceptions, but the problem is, that CommandService.ExecuteAsync().Error only returns the CommandError.Exception, with no way (as far as I can tell) to find out which type of exception was thrown.

My code is as follows:

```
try { var result = await _service.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos);

            if (!result.IsSuccess)
                switch (result.Error)
                {
                    case CommandError.BadArgCount:
                        await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Bad argument count.");
                        break;
                    case CommandError.UnknownCommand:
                        break;
                    case CommandError.Exception:
                        // This is what happens instead of the catch block.
                        break;
                    default:
                        await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"You  Broke  It ({result.ErrorReason})");
                        break;

                }
        }
        catch (Exceptions.GameCommandNotReadyException e)
        {
            // The code never gets here because of the CommandError.Exception
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not want to use try/catch there, as you would unnecessarily throw your own exception and then catch it directly afterwards. You can just put your error handling into the `case CommandError.Exception`.

If you want to know more about the exception that led to the error:

Since you're calling the `ExecuteAsync` function, it is likely that the "result" is not only of type `IResult`, but of type [ExecuteResult](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Commands.ExecuteResult.html). That would mean there is a property "Exception" that stores "what went wrong".

```
case CommandError.Exception:
    if (result is ExecuteResult execResult)
    {
        //you can now access execResult.Exception to see what happened
    }

break;
```